# StreamCorruptedException only in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, stream, dependencies

On a Spring Boot application (2.3.3), I have a dependency to a module developed by my company. From a service I'm calling a method from this dependency which needs a file loaded from resources (src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-main-cfg.xml), so I've copied and pasted this file to my Spring Boot application resources.

Here's the code executed in that dependency:

```
InputStream in = RSAEncrypter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyFileName);
// StreamCorruptedException here
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
```

Stack:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:936) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:394) ~[na:1.8.0_281]

The thing is, I've created a new dummy Maven project with only this dependency and a main to execute that code and it works.

I don't understand what could be the reasons I've got this exception executed from my Spring Boot application. I've got the same Java version, the file read is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reading a file called `spring-main-cfg.xml` using `ObjectInputStream` makes zero sense.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, that is great, but please do not edit the solution into your **question**. You need to post the solution as an **answer**, and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the issue, it was the file it self since I had a global:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

The Maven doc on this say:

> Warning: Do not filter files with binary content like images! This will most likely result in corrupt output.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

So I just added an exception for my file :

```
<resources>
  <!-- Only properties files have to be filtered.
       META-INF/spring-main-cfg.xml must not be or StreamCorruptedException occure by reading it -->
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```